# mySql return selected fields in select when using if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

When using `if exists` with a `select`, how can I get it to return the `id` or what ever field or fields I want it to display, or 'Does not exist'?

`SELECT IF(EXISTS( SELECT id, dateIn FROM table WHERE id = 10), my selected fields here, 'Does not exist')`

Or is there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 10)
    SELECT id, otherFields FROM table WHERE id=10
ELSE
    SELECT 'Does not exist' FROM table
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use the values from the first select if they exist, just like I've done in my question, rather than doing it twice?

Comment: AFAIK, no. But to be honest, I don't think you should use the DB to tell you that your data 'Does not exist'. As I assume you'll use the data in some program, why not just select your data and deal on the program layer if the result contains 0 rows, outputting some 'Does not exist' message ?

Comment: This'll be used in pagination. That's why.

Comment: I don't see the link with pagination. Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same variable you can use it like this, givev that its used in a Stored Procedure

```
BEGIN

SELECT  id, otherFields INTO @id,@otherFields FROM table WHERE Id = 10;

IF (@id IS NOT NULL) then
SELECT  @id,@otherFields;
ELSE
SELECT 'Not exist';
END IF;

END
```

Comment: I'm using this in a php script. Wont be using a stored procedure.

Comment: Ok, so why cant you just the define variable, check its values and then perform the IF?

Comment: Please post if your using php or just sql coding, then i would not have wasted 10 mins of my morning :) hehe good luck.